# Jquery make listeners work even if some elements are not present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS, this is for my one of class project.

I had some buttons with inline onclick for selecting some checkboxes.

To clarify it further more:

> Page 1 has button named 1. Page 2 has button named 2.  Page 3 has both
>   button 1 and 2

Then I tried to get rid of inline onclick using Jquery and this code. This is the code I'm using for Button 1 and Button 2.

```html
var btn = document.querySelector("button.buttona-1");
btn.addEventListener("click", selectArts);
function selectArts() {
    unselectAll();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    $('#ch_1, #ch_2').prop('checked', !0)
}


var btn = document.querySelector("button.buttonb-2");
btn.addEventListener("click", selectBusiness);
function selectBusiness() {
    unselectAll();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    $('#ch_3, #ch_4').prop('checked', !0)
}
```

Issue is I'm getting console errors for page 1 and page 2 because not all the buttons are present there.

Only page 3 is working fine because it has both buttons.

How do I fix this? Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the DOM directly for the click handlers. If you'd used jQuery instead, you wouldn't have had the problem, see `***` comments:

```
$("button.buttona-1").on("click", selectArts);     // ***
function selectArts() {
    unselectAll();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    $('#ch_1, #ch_2').prop('checked', !0)
}


$("button.buttonb-2").on("click", selectBusiness); // ***
function selectBusiness() {
    unselectAll();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    $('#ch_3, #ch_4').prop('checked', !0)
}
```

The reason that works is that jQuery is *set-based*. It's fine that the set may be empty, you can still do operations on the set (they'll just be "no-ops" — e.g., they do nothing). Whereas with your original code, you were trying to call `addEventListener` on `null` because `querySelector` returns `null` if it can't find a matching element (the DOM is not set-based).

Of course, if you didn't want to use jQuery for that bit for some reason, you'd just add a guard:

```
var btn;

btn = document.querySelector("button.buttona-1");
if (btn) {                                         // ***
    btn.addEventListener("click", selectArts);
}
function selectArts() {
    unselectAll();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    $('#ch_1, #ch_2').prop('checked', !0)
}

btn = document.querySelector("button.buttonb-2");
if (btn) {                                         // ***
    btn.addEventListener("click", selectArts);
}
function selectBusiness() {
    unselectAll();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    $('#ch_3, #ch_4').prop('checked', !0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Cleared every doubt I had.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent error you need to check the element exist or not before you can actually assign the `click` event handler to the element. Change you code to check the element existence by comparing with `null` or `undefined`

```
var btn = document.querySelector("button.buttona-1");
if (btn)
{
   btn.addEventListener("click", selectArts);
}
function selectArts() {
    unselectAll();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
    $('#ch_1, #ch_2').prop('checked', !0)
}

var btn = document.querySelector("button.buttonb-2");
if (btn)
{
  btn.addEventListener("click", selectBusiness);
}
function selectBusiness() {
    unselectAll();
    let boxes = $(".scores").toArray();
}
```

Comment: `if (typeof(btn) != 'undefined' && btn != null)` is quite a complicated check given you know you'll either get an element reference (truthy) or `null` (falsy)... :-) (Also: `typeof` is an operator, not a function, no need for `()` around its operand.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the suggestion and pointing those. Edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Before adding the event listener you can check whether the DOM element is null or not.

```
if(btn){
   //your code
}
```